# Store and protect details for software licenses

Tags: compliance, configuration

Assuming that a license can be a key (`XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX`), a file (`license.xml` or whatever), or a login for a dashboard on the vendor website, how would be a standard way to store and secure those licenses?

I thought of getting a external HD or a flash drive, store, encrypt, inform the password for the people responsible of handling these licenses. I also thought of using a tool like KeePass, but it won't work with licenses that comes in configuration files.

Comment: The best suited solution will depend very much on your specific usage scenario. Is this for your personal use /small business or corporate that you are trying to solve this problem?

Comment: @ilikebeets it is in a corporate scenario

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attachment feature in saving password in Keepass to store your files highly-encrypted, but Keepass or other software solutions like Lastpass have the risk of being a single point of failure!

The protection of all information depends on keeping one master password safe. If you forget it or someone sniffs your master password, all will be gone!